# Incrementing src by one each 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, setinterval, increment, src

Hello I am making a custom gallery and every 3 seconds I want the src to update by 1 I have had a couple attempts at it and this is my code:

```
function gallery1(src1) {
    var src = src1;
    document.getElementById('main_photo').src = "img/" + src + ".png";
    setInterval(function() {
        src++;
    }, 3000);
}
```

the src's are easy to increment is upose as they are 1.png 2.png and so on

Comment: And what is your problem? Do you gett any error messages?

Comment: Without seeing the rest of the code, im guessing you are incrementing src, but then assigning it a new value each time the function is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var src = 0;
var timer = setInterval(updateGallery, 3000);

function updateGallery() {
    document.getElementById('main_photo').src = "img/" + src + ".png";
    src++;
}
```

And you can use 
clearInterval(timer); 
To stop updating the images

Comment: Hello this works great but I also have thumbnails which automatically take you to the picture that you choose, that's why the "src1" was necessary hope you can help Andrew.

Comment: So why not use something like document.getElementById('main_photo').src = "img/thumbnail" + src + ".png"; Of course, you would have to name the images and thumbnails (thumbnail1.png and 1.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one..

```
  var x = 0;
  function gallery1(src1){
    document.getElementById('main_photo').src = "img/" +src1+ ".png";
    setInterval(function(){
       x+=1;
       gallery2(x);
    },3000);
  }

  function gallery2(src1){
     document.getElementById('main_photo').src = "img/" +src1+ ".png";
  }
```

Maybe this helps, you might want to take a look at this sample http://jsfiddle.net/markipe/bHxym/1/

Answer (score 0):

the problem here is u r updating the variable's value every 3 seconds. You should update the source infact.

Following should work :

```
function gallery1(src1) {
var src = src1;
setInterval(function() {
    src++;
   document.getElementById('main_photo').src = "img/" + src + ".png";
}, 3000);}
```

Comment: Hello works great but I have a list of thumbnails that link to that specific photo and when I click each of them which they are declared in src1 they do not go to them